# How to switch to user perspective in Blender

Tags: blender

I've just started using Blender (v2.63) for the first time. I have used a lot of 3d modelling programs in the past but Blender's controls seem to be set up differently and it's taking a while to get used to it. The thing that is really bugging me at the moment is switching from user perspective to front/side/top views. I have my view in perspective mode and I want to switch to front view in orthographic mode and then switch back to the view I had before. It seems that the only way is to press numpad-0 to go to camera view, rotate the screen a bit to get rid of the annoying black outline and then switch it back to perspective mode. Then sometimes when I go back to front view it's in perspective mode which is annoying as you never want front view in perspective, only orthographic mode.

My question: Is there a way I can be in my user view in perspective mode, switch to front/side/top views in orthographic mode and then switch back to where I was before in my user mode and be back in perspective mode?

Comment: I answer to the part where you said you used other 3D programs. If you come from 3D Studio Max you might be adapted to Quad View and you might want to activate this as seen here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#quad-view
I was searching for this and come across this page. I believe it is related in some way.

Answer (score 5):

Use :

- Numpad 1 for front orthographic view.
- Numpad 3 for right orthographic view
- And numpad 7 for top orthographic view

For your own custom perspective you can use either your camera (numpad 0 to go back to it)

or use a second 3d view panel as explained here
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames

> Splitting a window
>   Manual-Interface-Window System-Arranging frames-splitwidget.png
>   In the upper right and lower left corners of a window are the window splitter widgets, and they look like a little ridged thumb grip. It both splits and combines window panes. When you hover over it, your cursor will change to a cross. LMB Template-LMB.png and drag it to the left to split the pane vertically, or downward to split it horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, you can't go back to your previous perspective or undo your perspective change.
But there is a workaround in case that you often need to switch fast between two perspectives:
[Screens](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Screens)

Because every screen layout saves its own perspective settings, you can easily add a new layout and change the perspective to your alternate view. If your current screen is called Default, just click on the "+" button. As the names within the screens list are always sorted alphanumerically, I recommend to keep them in neighborhood so you can toggle between them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→ (Right Arrow)</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to orthographic mode is not the same as changing to top side or front view.  to switch from perspective to orthographic mode press num  pad 5.  Or go to view (bottom left) >> view Persp/ortho (toggle button).  Just to clarify, when you are in front view it does not mean you are in orthographic front view.  Look at the top left of your screen it will say "front/right ortho" or "front/right persp" depending on whether you switched to orthographic or to perspective previously.